# Share dependency libraries between modules

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, dependencies

I have a project layout as follows:

```
+-- app
|   +-- builds
|   +-- libs
|   +-- src

+-- my-lib
|   +-- builds
|   +-- libs
|   |   +-- lib1.jar
```

I have already added my-lib as `implementation project (':my-lib')` in `app` module, how do I use `lib1` classes inside `app` module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `my-lib1` library dependency section use `api` instead of `implementation` to include the `lib1` library like below.

```
dependecies {
     api files('libs/lib1.jar')

     ... some other libraries ...
}
```

**tl;dr**

Difference between `api` and `implementation` is explained like below in [gradle docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html) website.

> The `api` configuration should be used to declare dependencies which are
>   exported by the library API, whereas the `implementation` configuration
>   should be used to declare dependencies which are internal to the
>   component.

**Impacts on using `api`**
It'll increase the build time if you are doing any changes in `lib1`. Because it need to rebuild your `my-lib` and `app`. In your case it won't happen. Check this [reference article](https://medium.com/mindorks/implementation-vs-api-in-gradle-3-0-494c817a6fa) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for your time Mahendran. Still not working, any other option?

Comment: @Eduardo Could you please post your code. So that i can check and let u know.

Comment: Thnaks for your help Mahendran, I just fixed this adding my lib as an Android Library and set the .jar that is inside this lib as API.

Comment: @Eduardo I hope that's the same i mentioned in the answer. So if you feel the above one is valid, except it as answer. If not post your answer and accept it.